# get elements that are present in list1 but not in list2 (like set operation A - B)

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have two lists, list1 and list2, I want to get all elements that are present in list1 but not in list2. Currently, I am typecasting lists into set and subtracting them and then again typecasting result to list.

```
list(set(list1) - set(list2));
```

But this is not performance efficient. Can you please suggest me alternate ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension is probably simplest:

```
[x for x in list1 if not x in list2]
```

Comment: With simplicity, you should also check the performance.

Comment: not working as expected.

Comment: I guess the duplicated marked question helps.